Relationship between release height of magnet and induced EMF through a solenoid
I'm doing an experiment where a magnet is dropped vertically into a solenoid at varying heights above a solenoid placed vertically. I was expecting to a see a square-root shape graph as velocity is directly proportional to the square root of the height of displacement
$
\frac12mv^2 = mgh
$ and hence $v=\sqrt{2gh}$.
 However as shown in the graph below, I recorded a linear trend. I've tried deriving a few formulae to explain the trend but none explain a square root shape. I'd appreciate any assistance in why the results show this linear relationship rather than a square-root trend. Thanks.


Can you explain why this plot has voltage against displacement and how that relates to velocity versus displacement? Or is the question of why there is a linear relationship between velocity and displacement separate to the experiment?

There is another problem with the plot shown: the voltage does not go to zero if the height goes to zero! (At least if the "displacement" is meant as the height $h$, if not you have to explain what it is...)
